# IDEA maven dependency diagram is not work will(tree/balloon layout)

Tags: intellij-idea

my idea maven dependency diagram has no tree layout and balloon layout, since idea 2017, it's not work any more.
now i'm using 2018.1 but also not work and i don't know why.
any body can help?

[image]

Comment: well, it doesn't work now either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please vote for the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176829